# How do I build a docker image that has the same tag as the base image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a case where I want to create a docker image from some base image making a couple of modifications along the way (as you do) and I'm looking for some way to **preserve** the base image tag.

Let me elaborate with an example.

I want to build a new logstash image, with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:5.5.2
RUN /opt/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-jdbc
RUN mkdir /opt/logstash/vendor/jdbc
RUN curl -Lo /opt/logstash/vendor/jdbc/postgresql-42.1.1.jar https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.1.1.jar
```

I would like the resulting image to also end up with tag `5.5.2`, just like the original base image.

I know I can simply tag it from the command line once the build is done, but I am looking for some way (if one exists) to either:

- "extract" this tag from the Dockerfile, so i can use it in the `docker build -t` option
- pass some variable into the Dockerfile that can be used in place of the `5.5.2` image tag

Thanks for your help & ideas!

Comment: You can use [docker build args](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use build arguments in your docker file

```
ARG LOGSTASH_VERSION
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:${LOGSTASH_VERSION}
RUN /opt/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-jdbc
RUN mkdir /opt/logstash/vendor/jdbc
RUN curl -Lo /opt/logstash/vendor/jdbc/postgresql-42.1.1.jar https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.1.1.jar
```

Then pass the value using docker build command line

```
docker build --build-arg LOGSTASH_VERSION=5.5.2 .....
```